# Display Google App Engine datastore value as selected option in HTML select input

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

I have a value stored in Google App Engine datastore, selected from a dropdown select control.

But every time I load the html page, it does not show me the stored datastore value. Instead it shows the original dropdown select with no option selected.

HTML:

```
<select name="items">
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeType = function() {
        var data = [{"user":"a","name":"Mr A"},
                    {"user":"b","name":"Miss B"},
                    {"user":"c","name":"Mrs C"}];
        var tlist = '<option>Select<\/option>';
        $.each(data, function(i,d){
            tlist += '<option value="' + d.user + '">' + d.name + '<\/option>';
        });
        $("select", this).html(tlist);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

main.py:

```
# assume model s
user = db.StringProperty()
...
updated_user = self.request.get('items')
s.user = updated_user
s.put()
```

Note that I only store the user (value) part (eg a) in the datastore, but I would like to have the name part (eg Mr A). Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Update:
Sorry for not being clear. I was using jinja2 with a template value p which draws from the model s

```
<select name="items">
    <option>{{ p.user }}</option>
</select>
```

and also tried putting this in the jQuery:

```
var tlist = '<option>{{ p.user }}<\/option>';
```

but there was no effect (well it sort of shows the user (value) part for a split second). Essentially I would like to ask what and where do I put the Google App Engine datastore value in my HTML and jQuery. Thanks.

Update 2:
I changed the JavaScript to

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeType = function() {
        var data = [{"user":"a","name":"Mr A"},
                    {"user":"b","name":"Miss B"},
                    {"user":"c","name":"Mrs C"}];
        var tselected = $("select option:selected").val();
        var tlist = '<option>Select<\/option>';
        $.each(data, function(i,d){
    if (d.user === tselected)
                tlist += '<option value="' + d.user + 'selected="selected">' + d.name + '<\/option>';
            else
                tlist += '<option value="' + d.user + '">' + d.name + '<\/option>';
        });
        $("select", this).html(tlist);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

but tselected does not appear to return the current selected value. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: But you don't seem to have any code to get the value from the datastore and display it, so of course it's just showing you the default. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's the key point. How do I get the value from the datastore and display it (I am using jinja2).

Comment: Solved using input hidden value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using input hidden value.